# pre tag width:100% or max-width:100% overflow:auto is not flexible

Tags: html, css

Here is a link to an example:
http://whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/the_img_tag_and_its_attributes.html

My  tag element will contain long lines of code. Whenever its container changes to a width:auto (below 1200px width) the  tag will not shrink in width. I would like the window to keep shrinking and the  element to have a scroll bar for the width.

Currently I have this css:

> pre {overflow:auto; max-width:100%}

Comment: Let's reinvent all the wheels... sorry I coundn't stop myself. Open DevTools and change `white-space` to any other value (default is `pre`)

Comment: I want the behavior of pre, just a flexible width with scroll box. minimize my page below a width of 1200px to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I've added breakpoints as a workaround. The problem continues to be in the container. Whenever my container doesn't have a set width, the embedded <pre> tag will take up as much width as its contents allows. I do not want this. I would like the width to shrink with the window and the scroll bar to be present.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I added this css to my `display:table;` container:

```
table-layout:fixed;
width: 100%;
```

CSS `display:table` layouts are harder to style. If you're just starting out, just use float to position divs in a container.

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed values in your css files, look at the styles of `pre` when < `1200px`

**article_two_column.css:101**

`@media only screen and (min-width: 336px) {`...

**article_two_column.css:103**

```
pre {
    max-width: 260px; 
}
```

**article_two_column.css:87**

`@media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {` ...

**article_two_column.css:89**

```
pre {
    max-width: 652px;
}
```

Set the values to `%` and you will get a fluid result (remember you can also set decimals not only int's).

Comment: Using `max-width:100%;` will not work. The problem has to do with its container becoming fluid at 1200px. I believe the `<pre>` tag needs a fixed width container for `overflow:auto` to work. And I don't think the `<pre>` tag can be fluid with `overflow:auto`;

Comment: Nope I was wrong. I tested it here: http://whiterootmedia.com/test/fluid_pre_tags/test1.html. Still can't get my article <pre> tag working, but I will win.

Comment: Found the problem: `#body_container{display:table; }`

Comment: Still trying to come up with an easy solution. Here's my test page: http://whiterootmedia.com/test/fluid_pre_tags/test1.html and here's my actual article page with the problem: http://whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/the_img_tag_and_its_attributes.html.

Comment: specifying max-width for each media screen size was the only reliable way I could achieve this.